# How can I define two modules in one asn.1 file?

Tags: asn.1

When I'm trying to declare the following modules in test.asn1 file, the compile fails with the error:
file "test.asn1", line 9: syntax error at symbol "CDRR8"

The content of the file was:

```
CDR DEFINITIONS IMPLICIT TAGS ::=
BEGIN
ChangeCondition  ::= ENUMERATED
{
  qoSChange               (0),
  tariffTime              (1)
}
```

END

```
CDRR8 DEFINITIONS IMPLICIT TAGS ::=
BEGIN
ChangeCondition  ::= ENUMERATED
{
  qoSChange               (0),
  tariffTime              (1)
}
END
```

Trying google but found nothing about this. Why can't I define two modules in the same file? Could anybody help point out the reason for this error ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your syntax.  It may be that the tool you are using doesn't support having multiple module definitions in a single file.

Comment: Could be, I'm using snacc for compilation.